# Migration from MAc(using Wamp) to Windows (using XAmpp )

Tags: joomla, migration, xampp, mamp

i originally developed and design my website on MAMP, then my professor(because the project is for my thesis ) tried to work it on windows pc with Xampp

we followed all the techniques to migrate our database

but when we try to open it through localhost we can't reach the website.

I know that the description might sound a bit novice but i would be really pleased if someone can at least give me a  manual on how to do this kind of migration !

Thanks a lot !! :)

Comment: define "can't reach the website". Are you getting any errors? Blank page? etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is not just a database, it's a database and the files in your websites directory.

The most reliable way to move a Joomla website is to use the Backup extension from [Akeeba](https://www.akeebabackup.com).

1. Download an install [Akeeba Backup](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-backup.html). Documentation [here](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-backup-documentation.html).
2. Run a backup.
3. Copy the backup file from `/administrator/components/com_akeeba/backup/`
   It will have a name like `site-mywebsite.com-20131206-090807.jpa`
4. Put the `jpa` backup file on the target computer/server (your Professors PC)
   (*You will need to put it in the directory you want to serve it from*)
5. Download and install [Kickstart](https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-kickstart.html) from Akeeba.
6. Using a browser load the website directory (on the professors pc) that you put the `jpa` and kickstart files into.
7. Follow the Kickstart script making sure you read each step carefully ([Documentation](https://www.akeebabackup.com/documentation/akeeba-kickstart-documentation.html)).